# Xcode can't find my private key in keychain

Tags: xcode, macos, certificate, key, publish

I have some apps already published in iTunes, I've compiled and published them from my Mac many times. Recently I was forced to reset my passwords, and then I tried to compile and XCode told me that:

a) I wasn't logged in

b) My certificate wasn't found in the keychain (Revoke)

So, ok, I logged in again and created another certificate. I read in another post that: "If you change your password for your computer after you have already created a cert, you will have to go through the process all over again and create new certs."

But now when I'm going to compile, XCode tells me that my private key can't be found in my keychain. And I can't create a new one because my app is already published. Where is it?

All the info I could find on the web tells me to contact the owner of the Mac which originally created the private key to import it to mine. But it's my Mac! Where is it? Where is the private key? Gone?

Answer (score 0):

Try going into Keychain Access, type in "iPhone Developer" or "iPhone Distribution" into the search field in the top right and you'll get a list of valid and expired certificates. 
[image: Private Key Found in Keychain Access]

As you can see from the below screenshot, I have a pile of expired ones, and one valid one.  Clicking on that valid cert reveals the private key underneath it.